# Error handler import works only after we adding all app_rules

Tags: python, flask

Why is the code marked NOT WORKING, not working and throwing a respective error? What is the right way to do it ? `import *` is not the right way.

My `routing.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from views import UserView

#App Config
app= Flask(__name__)

# ********************** NOT WORKING ****************************
# from error_handlers import auth_error ==> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: user_view 
# from error_handlers import * ==> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: user_view
# ***************************************************************

#URLs
app.add_url_rule('/users', view_func=UserView.as_view('user_view'), methods=['GET'])

# ********************** NOT WORKING ****************************
# from error_handlers import auth_error ==> ImportError: cannot import name auth_error
# ***************************************************************

# ********************** WORKING ****************************
from error_handlers import *
# ***************************************************************

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port=5050)
```

`error_handlers.py` is:

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify

from routing import app
from myexceptions import *

#Error Handlers

@app.errorhandler(404)
def unexpected_error(error):
    """ error handler for unknown error """
    return render_template('error.html'), 404


@app.errorhandler(AuthenticationException)
def auth_error(error):
    """ error handler user entered data exception """
    return jsonify({'error': error.get_message()})
```

`views.py` is:

```
from flask.views import View
from flask import render_template

from myexceptions import AuthenticationException

class ParentView(View):
    def get_template_name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def render_template(self, context):
        return render_template(self.get_template_name(), **context)

    def dispatch_request(self):
        context = self.get_objects()
        return self.render_template(context)

class UserView(ParentView):
    def get_template_name(self):
        raise AuthenticationException('test')
        return 'users.html'

    def get_objects(self):
        return {}
```

and `AuthenticationException` is just a `Exception` subclass defined in `myexceptions`.

Comment: Please create a reproducible sample **here**, not in a GitHub repository.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sure. Do I have to edit anything after this?

Comment: It might be possible to further shorten it to the minimum to reproduce the problem; if you can feel free.

Answer (score 0):

I'v also read your code in your github before,maybe the error is : you  import app  in some files which doesn't use app

My modifid code :

routing.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask


#App Config
app= Flask(__name__)

from views import UserView
app.add_url_rule('/users', view_func=UserView.as_view('user_view'), methods=['GET'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print app.url_map
    app.run(debug=True, host = '10.210.71.145', port=5050)
```

and your error_handle.py maybe like this:

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify

from myexceptions import AuthenticationException


@app.errorhandler(404)
def unexpected_error(error):
    """ error handler for unknown error """
    return render_template('error.html'), 404


@app.errorhandler(AuthenticationException)
def auth_error(error):
    """ error handler user entered data exception """
    return jsonify({'error': error.get_message()})
```